# Issues with Creating WiFi Hotspot on Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspbian Bookworm) using USB Modem Connection

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, raspberry-pi, wifi-hotspot

I am encountering difficulties while trying to set up a WiFi hotspot on my Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian Bookworm. Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Flashed the OS image and configured WiFi during the installation.
2. Connected a USB modem, activated it, and it appeared as eth1.
3. Attempted to share this connection as a WiFi hotspot using the provided script.

However, I am facing two main issues:

- The WiFi network sometimes doesn't show up.
- When it does, clients are unable to connect due to an "IP configuration error."

I executed the following script to start the wifi hotspot.

```
## Share WiFi
wifissid=qwerqwer
wificode=qwertyuio
# Disconnect from current Wi-Fi network
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down

# Stop NetworkManager and configure so it doesn't start on reboot
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager

# Disconnect from current Wi-Fi network again, just in case
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down

# Stop services if already running
sudo systemctl stop hostapd
sudo systemctl stop dnsmasq

# Unmask hostapd
sudo systemctl unmask hostapd

# Configure a static IP for the WiFi interface (adjust interface and IP accordingly)
sudo bash -c 'echo "interface wlan0" >> /etc/dhcpcd.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24" >> /etc/dhcpcd.conf'

# Configure hostapd
sudo bash -c "cat > /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf <<EOF
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=$wifissid
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=$wificode
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
EOF"

# Update hostapd configuration
sudo bash -c 'echo "DAEMON_CONF=\"/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf\"" >> /etc/default/hostapd'

# Configure dnsmasq
sudo mv /etc/dnsmasq.conf /etc/dnsmasq.conf.orig
sudo bash -c 'echo "interface=wlan0" > /etc/dnsmasq.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "dhcp-range=192.168.4.2,192.168.4.20,255.255.255.0,24h" >> /etc/dnsmasq.conf'

# Enable IP forwarding
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo bash -c 'echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf'

# Enable NAT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
sudo sh -c 'iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat'

# Create the directory if it doesn't exist
sudo mkdir -p /lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks

# Restore iptables on boot
sudo bash -c 'echo "iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat" >> /lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/70-ipv4-nat'

# Start services
sudo systemctl start hostapd
sudo systemctl start dnsmasq
```

I run the above script using `nohup` to prevent disconnections from local wifi ssh to prevent it from completing.

I tried restarting services, making sure hostadb conf is written correctly. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Logs on hostapd and dnsmasq services look fine (running). Logs indicate successful associations with the Wi-Fi network. However, there are several DHCP packet received errors in the dnsmasq logs, suggesting an issue with IP address assignment.

Note: I also tried using NetworkManager, but no success there either.